# Topleft and bottom right points in android google maps version 2 monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2

newly I switched to Google Maps version 2 for android in my monodroid project. in version 1 by using `LatitudeSpan` and center point of a the map view we can execute the topleft and bottomright point's lat o lng but in new version how we can find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android directly `GoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion()`. [`VisibleRegion`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion.html) has things like `nearLeft`, `farRight` and also `latLngBounds`. I don't know if anything changes when you use mono.